# Cloning Echium pininana

Tags: fungus, rot

I'm asking how to clone an Echium pininana.

I have a single Echium pininana in my pot but unfortunately it's root has rotted due to excessive rain and bad soil, the plant is 30cm high and 6 months old. The bottom 5cm has rotted and is infected with fungus Athelia rolfsii.

For pictures see :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSkKD.jpg

I have access to tissue culture labs but I have no idea how to clone it from the healthy parts, where should I cut? Can anybody help? Or perhaps it's possible to use air-layering technique to grow a new set of roots?

I'm also trying to restart from seed, but the seeds I have is very hard to germinate, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

[Echium pininana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echium_pininana) is a biennial or triennial from the Canary Islands.  It is now grown in England and Wales as a garden plant.

The best way to propagate this plant is from seed.  It is available [here](http://www.thompson-morgan.com/flowers/flower-seeds/perennial-and-biennial-seeds/echium-pininana/6227TM).  Instructions from this site are

> Sow 3mm (1/8in) deep in good seed sowing compost from late May-late
> July. Germination takes 7-14 days at 18-20C (65-70F). When large
> enough to handle, transplant the seedlings to 7.5cm (3in) pots and
> over-winter in a cool greenhouse, conservatory or on a well lit
> windowsill with a temperature of around 7C (45F). Plant out the
> following spring 1m (3ft) apart, into a sunny site with well drained
> soil.

Your specimen is in poor shape and I don't think you can get a healthy cutting from it.  Cultivation tips include protecting from wind and a well drained soil. New plants from seed will be more successful than anything from a weakened plant.

Comment: I have plenty of seeds, but they don't germinate well. I've sown 20 seeds in different substrates but most failed to germinate, instead they grow mould after a few weeks. That's why I really wanted to save this one.

The temperature here is around 30~35 during the day and it's pretty hard to get to the best temperature for germination. I got 2 seeds that germinated in sterile agar substrates, but they stopped growing immediately after extending a tiny piece of root about 2mm.

Comment: @seilgu  Timing is important with seeds.  For best success you need reasonably fresh seed  (ie not many years old and that has been stored in optimum conditions (cool and dry)) and sown at the best time.  Given the instructions above the best time would seem to be your winter when there are cooler temperatures

Comment: I buy fresh seeds from abroad. I might not have the best germinating conditions, but I'm really eager to grow it now rather than having to wait for 6 months of my life...